# How to return a specific key value of dictionary without using any for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

x={1: [6, 3], 4: [6, 9]}

For example the result could return only the first key or the second key.

Comment: You can `print(x.keys())`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you want to print any random key?

Comment: x.keys() would actually print both the keys. I want to print individual key

Comment: yes i want to print a random key

Comment: `import random` and `print(random.choice(list(x.keys())))`

Comment: what if i want a specific key value?

Comment: for value: `print(random.choice(list(x.values())))` for key and value: `print(random.choice(list(x.items())))`

Comment: `print(1)` should do the trick.

Comment: *"I want a random key but also a specific one, please help me understand what I actually want"*...

Comment: i want a specific key

Comment: What is wrong with `print(1)` then? What is that you actually want, why, how, ...?

Comment: print(1) would print 1. but I want to print a specific key of a dictionary. It could be any key

Comment: ***WHICH*** SPECIFIC KEY? And why? Where does that key come from? What does it have to do with the dictionary at all if you already have the key just print it.

Comment: i need to use specific keys of a dictionary. All the keys individually. The dictionary need not be the same. I just set an example. It could be any dictionary.

Comment: Why the 4 in "For example the result should give only 4."? It looks like a random key rather than a specific one

Comment: This is absolutely hopeless :D we told you how to print a specific key, a random key, all keys - but all that was apparently incorrect, you still want "a specific key" that does not fall into any of these three categories.

Comment: 4 is a specific key. I just set an example. Is there a way to use individual keys without any loop?

Comment: By the way this is a VERY good example of why giving too few / a single example is just to little information. An undoubtedly correct answer to the current question is `print(4)`, it fits all the requirements in the question.

Comment: So you *do* want a random key, which is what jvx8ss commented 25 minutes ago, congrats.

Comment: The thing is I am not using a single dictionary. so i cannot just use print(4).

Answer (score -1):

Convert the dictionary to a list of tuples and just access an element

```
key = list(x)[0]
```